# Where does mysql server store the stored procedure code?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In MS SQL Server, it lets you search across all the stored procedures for the instance of some text.  Does this exist in MySQL?

This is useful for trying to understand what the impact of changing the schema would be.

> "Show me all the code that involves TableX"

How would you query across all stored procedures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedures are stored in table `mysql.proc`. The code is in column `body`.

So you could query:

```
SELECT db, name, body FROM mysql.proc WHERE body REGEXP '[[:<:]]tablename[[:>:]]'
```